# Datatable Recors

Tags: c#

I have a datatable and it has 4 columns. My problem is some columns has same data, same date. I have to delete same data, same date. How can I delete dublicate data?

My Datatable:
In this table I have to delete 1 or 3 (Id) In code side with for or foreach loop. Because in the same date there is a same Isban.

Id  Name  Isban   Date

1    A     123     09.09.2010

2    B     123     10.09.2010

3    C     123     09.09.2010

4    A     234     11.09.2010

5    B     342     12.09.2010

Thanks You 
john

Comment: Are you using SQL in ODBC? What kind of database ?  What is C# about this question ?  Are you looping over each record individually ?

Comment: I can hardly see any relation to `asp.net` and `asp.net-mvc` in this question. Removing those tags. If there's a relation indeed please feel free to edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

A standard way to do this is to run a `select distinct` query to insert the distinct records into a new table, delete the existing table, and then rename the new table to the previous table.

Edit: You can that you have to do this client-side.

One way is addressed here: [Distinct in DataTable](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetdataset/thread/ed9c6a6a-a93e-4bf5-a892-d8471b84aa3b)

Alternatively, loop through the table and store in a hash table each record; use the pair Isban/Date as the key and the record as the value. When you encounter a duplicate record it will already be in the hash table so you pass over it. Then, you can create a new data table from the records in the hash table.

Comment: ı am using sql server, but I have to do this in code side not in database.

Comment: can not we do it with for or foreach loop?

Comment: @John: Read my answer. I told you what to do in the loop.

Comment: sorry really I m the new in asp.net there is any example?

Answer (score 0):

If you DO have to do it in a loop, I would do it something like the following... Pre-query based on the minimum ID based on the given duplicate entitie elements, then delete for NOT being the minimum key

```
Select
      FldDup1,
      FldDup2,
      min( IDKey ) as KeepThisID,
      count(*) as TotalPerDupFields
   from
      YourTable
   group by
      FldDup1,
      FldDup2
   having
      TotalPerDupFields > 1
```

In this case, you'll end up with a sample result of...

```
FldDup1   FldDup2      KeepThisID    TotalPerDupFields
123       09.09.2010   1             2
```

as I was ignoring the 2nd column of "A", "B" and "C" as it didn't appear to be the indicator in your explanation of duplicates.

Then, I would isse a delete... via parameterized SQL-Delete query

```
Delete from YourTable
   Where FldDup1 = ResultQuery.FldDup1
     and FldDup2 = ResultQuery.FldDup2
     and NOT IDKey = ResultQuery.KeepThisID
```